# action object showing up as undefined in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to run some async code using redux and redux thunk. For whatever reason. When I try to run the code action is showing up as undefined and I get the following error.

`Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

All my action creators return an object with type so I'm not sure what it is sad about.

I setup my store like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import App from '~/components/App';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as reducers from './redux';
// import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools';

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers(reducers),
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

const nimbus = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

My authentication.js file where I am getting the error is below

```
const AUTHENTICATING = 'AUTHENTICATING';
const NOT_AUTHED = 'NOT_AUTHED';
const IS_AUTHED = 'IS_AUTHED';

import { fbAuth, db } from '~/config/firebase';

function authenticating () {
  return {
    type: AUTHENTICATING
  }
}

function notAuthed () {
  return {
    type: NOT_AUTHED
  }
}

function isAuthed () {
  return {
    type: IS_AUTHED
  }
}

export function createUser (userData) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(authenticating());

    const email = userData.email;
    const password = userData.password;

    fbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
    }).then(() => {
      const user = fbAuth.currentUser;

      db.ref('/users/' + user.uid).set({
        username: userData.username,
        displayName: userData.displayName,
        uid: user.uid
      })
      dispatch(isAuthed());
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.warn('Error in createUser callback', error)
    });
  }
}

const initialState = {
  isAuthed: false,
  isAuthenticating: false
};

export default function authentication (state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTHENTICATING :
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticating: true
      }
    case NOT_AUTHED :
      return {
        isAuthenticating: false,
        isAuthed: false
      }
      case IS_AUTHED :
        return {
          isAuthenticating: false,
          isAuthed: true
        }
    default :
      return state
  }
};
```

Has anyone gotten a similar issue? I console.log in my createUser function before the return statement and it's not even getting there which I thought was weird. Also before I try and run the function action is defined. Really not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Where are you calling `createUser` from?

Comment: @JoshKelley I had `import createUser from '~/redux/modules/authentication'` instead of `import { createUser } from '~/redux/modules/authentication'`; Damn....Thanks for the hint!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you need to import module for your `createUser()` function.

Example:

```
import { createUser } from 'yourModulePath'
```